# Batch Program not Updating From Text File Properly

Tags: batch-file

I have a rather simple problem that I just can't seem to wrap my head around. At the current time I'm trying to write a game through batch(I know I should be using other things that are better for that, but I'm not). My problem is that it's not being updated on time but seems to be a turn behind everything. At the current moment that just equates to the HP not being read correctly until another command is issued.

This is the code

```
`:damageAdjuster
cls
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
    set line=%%a
    echo !line!
    set /a L=!L!+1
)

echo Testing Damage
echo.
echo 1) Deal Damage to HP
echo 2) Heal HP

set /a healthPoints=!line!
set /a hardHealth=17
set /a hostileDamage=%random%%%6 +1
set /a healthHeal=%healthPoints% +6
set /a healthDamage=%healthPoints%-%hostileDamage%

set input=
set /p input=Well...?:
if %input%==1 echo %healthDamage% >test.txt
if %input%==2 echo %healthHeal% >test.txt

if %healthPoints% gtr %hardHealth% (
echo %hardHealth% >test.txt
)

goto damageAdjuster`
```

L is specified and delayed expansion is enabled. Of course I could be going about this the wrong way, but this is just what I've come up with with zero experience in batch. Any help would be appreciated. Also, in case something along the lines of this actually works would it also work for remembering inventory and the like?

Comment: instead of using a for loop try a do/while loop (i know batch doen't 'natively' support do/while but there is a way) [Batch How To ...Mimic While Loops](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_while_loops.php)

Comment: Congratulations on trying to do this as a batch file. I don't understand what you're actually asking, though.

Comment: What about `set /a L+=1`   ?

Comment: wpenton - I will look into this, thank you.
Gabe - What's happening is that an HP amount is being written to a text file and then read back from that text file. What I'm trying to do is make it so that the HP that's being read back can never be higher than the hardHealth and can never be displayed higher than the hardHealth. What it's doing is setting the displayed HP higher than the hardHealth but then reverting to the hardHealth after another command is issued.
Endoro - Didn't change anything, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works exactly as you describe.  I think your problem limiting health is that you're testing the wrong variable in the last echo--you need to test what you are writing out, not what the current health value is.  Consider modifying your code as shown below:

```
if %input%==1 echo %healthDamage% >test.txt
if %input%==2 (
  echo %healthHeal% >test.txt

  if %healthHeal% gtr %hardHealth% (
    echo %hardHealth% >test.txt
  )
)
```